# Core data - to implement OneToMany relationship with cascade delete rule

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, cascading-deletes

Need help in implementing delete rule in a core data relationship , I gone through  all the article on the net but can't understand  to implement the delete rule , does creating relationship takes cares of deletion process (which I doubt ) , I have creates the below entity with rule , but on deleting a entry in List_Main  does not delete  the entry in list_Item  , I guess linking in not done (don't know how to do that )

I have two entity

Entity   --------Relation Ship ----   Destination ----   Inverse   ----       Properties ----   Delete Rule

List_main  --  Main_to_Item  ----    List_Item    ----- Item_to_Main  --   Optional  --    Cascade

List_Item --   Item_to_Main  -----    list_Main  ------   Main_to_Item  ---   optional ---     nullify

List_Main.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * list_Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * list_Reminder_Date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * list_Reminder_Flag;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *main_to_item;
@end

@interface List_Main (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addMain_to_itemObject:(List_Item *)value;
- (void)removeMain_to_itemObject:(List_Item *)value;
- (void)addMain_to_item:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMain_to_item:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

List_Item.h

```
@interface List_Item : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * list_Items;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * list_Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) List_Main *item_to_main;
```

Now when in first view user enters the List Name in List_main
FirstView.m

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"List_Main" inManagedObjectContext:context];


[newItem setValue:self.listName.text forKey:@"list_Name"];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    currentDate = [self  dateWithOutTime:currentDate];
    [newItem setValue:currentDate forKey:@"list_Reminder_Date"];
    [newItem setValue:NO forKey:@"list_Reminder_Flag"];
    // Save 
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSAssert(NO, @"Save should not fail");
        [self showAlert];
    }
```

After that the control goes to secondView to enter Item and makes entires in List_Item

secondView.m

```
    NSManagedObject *category1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"List_Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

    [category1 setValue:self.listName forKey:@"list_Name"];
    [category1 setValue:combinedThumbNail forKey:@"list_Items"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.context save:&error]) {
        NSAssert(NO, @"Save should not fail");
        [self showAlert];
    }
```

and I have a delete command for respective entity

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

Now how  should I implement the  delete rule using the relationship , really a showstopper for me  :((
If you can point out any good tutorial that  will also do

Comment: Are you using the visual Data Model tool in Xcode to build your NSManagedObject subclasses?

Comment: Ya , Subclass are created through the Data Model tool in Xcode